# How to use Dasher "in real life"options on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Dasher seems like a great app for typing without a keyboard, but I can't seem to integrate it with other apps.  The help file mentions some options to enable for real world use (like automatically having typed text go to the clipboard or another app), but I can't for the life of me see where to enable them.  I'm an ubuntu/linux newbie, maybe there's some assumption I'm unaware of.  Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

To launch it for direct-input mode, use:

```
dasher -a direct
```

It's not working well for me though, and with the new D-Bus AT-SPI2, that functionality [may be going away.](http://live.gnome.org/Accessibility/GNOME3#Dasher)